# LNK2005: " already defined error

Tags: c++, linker, redefinition

I am trying to use a global variable from separated .cpp files. I have got an init.h file as:

```
//init.h
#ifndef init
#define init
int a = 3;
#endif
```

I have got an init.cpp file as:
    `//init.cpp
    #include init.h`

Then finally my main.cpp file is:

```
//main.cpp
#include "init.h"
int main(void)
{
    while(1)
    {
    }
}
```

After this, I get the error:

```
1>init.obj : error LNK2005: "int a" (?a@@3HA) already defined in main.obj
1> ..deneme.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Why my `#infdef` control does not solve this problem?. I also tried using `#pragma once` but I got same error. What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 9):

You need to mark your variable as `extern` and define it only once in an implementation file.

As the code is now, you're breaking the **one definition rule**. The include guards don't help in this case, since all translation units that include that header re-define the variable.

What you actually need:

```
//init.h
#ifndef init
#define init
extern int a;
#endif
```

and the definition:

```
//init.cpp
#include "init.h"
int a = 3;
```

Also, **think twice before using globals**. What is it that you're actually trying to achieve?

Comment: well,  I forgot to wrote the init.cpp file which includes the init.h file also. Problem still goes on when I use extern.

Comment: @volkansezer that can't be right. Are you sure you didn't forget to remove the =3 from the header? Are you sure you declared it as extern in the header and not the implementation file?

Comment: yes you are right, I have changed it as you recommend and problem is solved, thank you very much. It was very important for me to achieve the same global variable from different source files, thanks again.